How can I swap select options based on the response of a previous select?
I tried following the instructions to use '#ajax' to try and get these values to swap but nothing seems to be happening:
<?php

namespace Drupal\webform_test\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class WebformTestForm extends FormBase {

    public function getFormId() {
        return 'webform_test_form';
    }

    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        $form['select_one'] = [
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => $this->t('Select One'),
            '#options' => [
                '1' => $this->t('One'),
                '2' => $this->t('Two'),
                '3' => $this->t('Three'),
            ],
            '#ajax' => [
                'callback' => '::selectAjaxCallback', // don't forget :: when calling a class method.
                'disable-refocus' => FALSE, // Or TRUE to prevent re-focusing on the triggering element.
                'event' => 'change',
                'wrapper' => 'select-two-wrapper', // This element is updated with this AJAX callback.
                'progress' => [
                'type' => 'throbber',
                'message' => $this->t('Verifying entry...'),
                ],
            ]
        ];

        $option_1 = [
            'A' => $this->t('A'),
            'B' => $this->t('B'),
            'C' => $this->t('C'),
        ];

        $option_2 = [
            'D' => $this->t('D'),
            'E' => $this->t('E'),
            'F' => $this->t('F'),
        ];

        $option_3 = [
            'G' => $this->t('G'),
            'H' => $this->t('H'),
            'I' => $this->t('I'),
        ];

        switch($form_state->getValue('select_one')) {
            case 'A': 
                $options = $option_1;
                break;
            case 'B':
                $options = $option_2;
                break;
            case 'C':
                $options = $option_3;
                break;
            default:
                $options = [];
        }

        $form['select_two'] = [
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => $this->t('Select Two'),
            '#options' => $options,
            '#prefix' => '<div id="select-two-wrapper">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        ];

        $form['managed_file'] = [
            '#type' => 'managed_file',
            '#title' => $this->t('Managed file'),
        ];

        $form['submit'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
        ];

        return $form;
    }

    public function selectAjaxCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        switch($form_state->getValue('select_one')) {
            case 'A': 
                $options = $option_1;
                break;
            case 'B':
                $options = $option_2;
                break;
            case 'C':
                $options = $option_3;
                break;
            default:
                $options = [];
        }
        $form['select_two']['#options'] = $options;
        return $form['select_two'];
    }

    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        
    }

    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    }
}


I hope I understood correctly what you question was. I adjusted your code to make the ajax call work.
I modified your ajax callback to be a static method and removed any other logic besides returning the select_two element.
Then, I updated your switch in the buildForm to have '1', '2', '3' instead of 'A', 'B', 'C' since the select_one does not have any A, B, C options.
And I added the "#empty_value" key to your two selects just to have an empty value, but you can remove that if you don't need it.
I also modified a bit the #ajax definition by removing some keys and changing the callback to an array.
Here's the adjusted code snippet:
<?php

namespace Drupal\webform_test\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class WebformTestForm extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'webform_test_form';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['select_one'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Select One'),
      '#options' => [
        '1' => $this->t('One'),
        '2' => $this->t('Two'),
        '3' => $this->t('Three'),
      ],
      '#empty_value' => '',
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [get_class($this), 'selectAjaxCallback'],
        'disable-refocus' => FALSE, // Or TRUE to prevent re-focusing on the triggering element.
        'wrapper' => 'select-two-wrapper', // This element is updated with this AJAX callback.
        'progress' => [
          'type' => 'throbber',
          'message' => $this->t('Verifying entry...'),
        ],
      ]
    ];

    $option_1 = [
      'A' => $this->t('A'),
      'B' => $this->t('B'),
      'C' => $this->t('C'),
    ];

    $option_2 = [
      'D' => $this->t('D'),
      'E' => $this->t('E'),
      'F' => $this->t('F'),
    ];

    $option_3 = [
      'G' => $this->t('G'),
      'H' => $this->t('H'),
      'I' => $this->t('I'),
    ];


    switch($form_state->getValue('select_one')) {
      case '1':
        $options = $option_1;
        break;
      case '2':
        $options = $option_2;
        break;
      case '3':
        $options = $option_3;
        break;
      default:
        $options = [];
    }

    $form['select_two'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Select Two'),
      '#options' => $options,
      '#empty_value' => '',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="select-two-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    $form['managed_file'] = [
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#title' => $this->t('Managed file'),
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

  public static function selectAjaxCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['select_two'];
  }

}


This works and solves my original question. It appears there is a separate issue but i'll open a different question for that.
When you answer select_one, answer select_two and upload an image and submit the ajax in the managed_file seems to wipe out the available answers in select_two and this causes drupal to return the error:
An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.
